# Populating array using a string + number

Tags: php

I've got an empty array and a string assigned to a variable.

```
$str = "fruits2015"
$arr = [];
$expectedLength = 3;
```

How can I populate arr with str + a number (starting from 0)? The arr length to match `expectedLength`.

```
$arr = ["fruits20150", "fruits20151", "fruits20152",];
```

Comment: Is this PHP code..?  It looks like Javascript to me..

Comment: @MaggsWeb: Thanks. I've updated my post. :)

Comment: why don't you just use a `for` loop and append those values together, its too simple

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @anonymous: Thanks. I can do the strings using a for-loop, but I do not know how to add it in to the array?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `for` loop as

```
$str = "fruits2015";
$arr = [];
$expectedLength = 3;
for($i = 0;$i<$expectedLength;$i++){
    $arr[$i] = $str.$i;
}
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for($i=0; $i<$expectedLength; $i++){

    $arr[] = "$str.$i";

}
```

Comment: @StuartWagner It's obviously a typo.

Comment: Thanks 'eagle-eyes' @StuartWagner

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but now your `$i<=$expectedLength` is off just a hair :P

Answer (score 0):

You can doing like this:

```
$str = "fruits2015";

$expectedLength = 3;
$arr=array();

for($i=0;$i<$expectedLength;$i++)
{
    array_push($arr,$str.$i);
}
print_r($arr);
```